# Locations to switch between WiFi and Ethernet

Tags: network, system-settings, macos

I have a new MacBook Pro and would like to know how to manage my connectivity within my own home with the following scenario

I have WiFi and can connect to that no problem

I also have a TP-LINK Powerline box in my main plug socket which I connect to via a Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (setup for a desk at home)

When I plug my ethernet cable in, the TP-LINK box doesn't pick up that the MacBook is connected. It is not faulty because it worked OK with my previous Windows PC

My question is: is this a situation whereby having 2 locations/configurations (one WiFi only, 1 Ethernet) would be the solution? Or is there a setting I do not have enabled which is causing the TP-LINK box to not recognise the MacBook ethernet connection when it is plugged in?

Many thanks

Comment: try by just turning of the wifi, but the reason why it does not connect via Cable might be another one

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be the order in which your Mac is looking to connect to a network. You network preference pane should list options like these for connecting to networks:

[image]

First check what the status is for your ethernet connection. Mine says "Cable Unplugged" because it is. If your says it is plugged in, but your connectivity is still via Wi-Fi, click the gear icon below that list and select "Set Service Order":

[image]

You'll then get a list like that allows you to reorder your network connections:

[image]

Simply drag "ethernet" to the top and that should solve your problem.